# Why does prophet Isaiah believe the world is flat

Tags: navi-prophets, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Why does prophet Isaiah believe the world is flat?

> He will raise a banner for the nations and gather the exiles of Israel; he will assemble the scattered people of Judah from the four corners of the earth. - [Isaiah 11:12-13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.11.12-13?lang=bi)

Comment: If you say "quarters", that doesn't mean 4 quarters. It means like "living quarters." If you say "corners", Isaiah could be referring to an infinitely sided polyhedron, which has corners but is not flat.

Comment: Why flat? Even with a globe you have the 4 corners: Alaska, Argentina, Russia and Australia, for example.

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's on a map (centered on the prime meridian) not a globe. On a globe you could just as easily argue that the four corners are Newfoundland, Patagonia, Britain, and South Africa. (Of course this is just an idiom...)

Comment: @DoubleAA - that's why I wrote "for example"! If you want to gather in everybody, just pick them all up from any 4 corners you want.

Comment: @DannySchoemann If any four points could be corners, then it's a pretty meaningless term, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA meaningless or metaphor?

Comment: the word "kanfot" is often translated as "corners" but why assume that they are literal, physical corners and not metaphorical "farthest reaches of the four directions"? Do we take every word of Isaiah literally?

Comment: @DannySchoemann For any given four points, meaningless. For a work of literature in general, metaphor. Your identifying four points you want to call corners doesn't help demonstrate anything.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I was trying to get a clarification from the OP why "4 corners" proved a flat earth. (Unless the flat earth is square, "4 corners" doesn't "prove" a flat earth any more than any other shape earth.)

Comment: maybe Is. was using k-n-f as "hidden parts" in the way he uses yikaneif in 30:20 as "hidden". Or maybe he agrees with the author of Tehillim  17 that k-n-f means wings and God is a bird.

Comment: First of all, Isaiah lived long before Pythagoras and Aristotle. What's the problem. Secondly, have you ever made hamentash? Even circles have corners.

Comment: If you will take corners literally, than you must assume he thought it was square, not just flat. and that the corners were found in the north south east and west, so diamond shaped really. Getting weird? Good.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a literal meaning but the way people speak. We still speak of "sunrise" and "sunset". The idiom of "the four corners", means the farthest away that one can go in any direction.

One example can be seen in [Megillas Esther](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16474#showrashi=true) when it refers to מהודו ועד קוש One of the possible explanations is that they were next to each other and he ruled from the far side of one back around to the far side of the other.